# Facebook application with video uploading capabilities

Tags: php, facebook, file-upload, fbml, xfbml

I need to upload video files through Facebook application and later visualize all uploaded videos so that people can vote for a video they like. I searched and read some articles, but I still have questions that are not completely clear for me:

- Is it better to use iframe or FBML
- If I use iframe is it possible to use `input type="file"` and PHP to handle the uploading just like on a normal page (not with Facebook PHP SDK)

Please give me an advice what direction to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading to Facebook using their API is notoriously difficult; first of all check out the thread on [the faceboook dev forum](http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=56407).

I would recommend doing it in an iframe, and you'll need about 60 cigarettes and several large whiskeys to get it working.

Comment: Thanks very much for the advice. Is is possible to upload the videos to my server using iframe and later visualize them in the application, would facebook allow this to me?